# For the following amplifier, why is the output voltage 0 when input voltage is 0?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current

The amplifier is the following class AB amplifier:

[image: amplifier]

For an input voltage of 0V, the output voltage is 0V. However, I don't understand why. My textbook does not delve into why this is the case.

(Also VBB/2 is large enough to turn on both transistors with no input voltage.)

Comment: Hint: What state are the BJTs in when the input is 0 V?

Comment: @ThePhoton VBB/2 is large enough to turn on the transistors

Comment: In that case, practically the  output might not be exactly 0 V. It will depend how well matched the BJTs are.

Comment: @ThePhoton The textbook assumes the transistors are perfectly matched

Comment: Assume both transistors have an effective resistance of Ron. So you have two x Ron in series from Vcc+ to Vcc-. What is the voltage at the midpoint of the two resistors?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It would be zero, but now my question becomes how do you find the effective resistance of a transistor?

Comment: @cojoye Ahhh, the devil's in the details. In this case, more specifically the biasing. Your circuit is demonstrative, rather than working example of how an AB class amplfiier would be constructed.

Comment: @cojoye You might look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/408804/38098) for \$r_e\$. (And maybe also glance at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252199/38098).)

Comment: @jonk I have looked at your prior responses however I have not been able to solve this issue.

Comment: @cojoye Hmm. Before I waste time when you are perfectly capable on your own, have you thought about breaking up the schematic like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rRKT.png) and analyzing each, separately?

Comment: @jonk I looked at the schematic in the link, however I still can't being my self to understand why output voltage should be zero?

Comment: @cojoye Okay. I just thought that might help by making you think a little differently. The example pair is taken from your schematic. What's missing in the separation, though, is a way to handle excess currents. So it was just an attempt to see if you could rotate things in your mind differently in order to get a handle on it. So tell me what you think you can say for certain about your schematic and then lead me to where you "just get stuck." You've never said a word yet about what is going on in YOUR mind about it. Only that you don't get it. What do you think it should be and why?

Comment: @jonk My initial observations are that if input voltage is 0 then the voltage at the base of transistor Qn is VBB/2 and -VBB/2 for Qp. Therefore the base emitter voltage for transistor Qn is VBB/2 - Vout and the emitter base voltage is Vout + VBB/2 for transistor Qp. Given that these two quantities are not equivalent, this implies that the currents passing through both transistors are not equal therefore there must be a current that flows through RL which implies Vout is non zero. This reasoning is what has lead me to believe that Vout is not 0V however my textbook states it is 0V for Vin = 0

Comment: @cojoye Suppose, though, that \$v_o\$ is zero. Do you then find that these are the same? I suspect that we may be moving into some more serious mathematics, though. I can prove the case. But if you want a closed equation and not hand-waving I'll need to use a function about which I'm pretty sure you've not yet heard... the product-log function. Is that what you want? Or is a bunch of hand-waving good enough?

Comment: @cojoye You seem to have gone right past my answer above - which you correctly responded to without noticing it answer your question. The effective resistance of the transistors is IRRELEVANT as long as it is equal in each case, & by YOUR definition, it is. You have two R's between two supplies symmetrically balanced. Their mid point is zero. Your midpoint is zero. That's your answer. Yes? || Remove Rl. Do calculations. Vmidpoint = 0. Vout (disconnected) is 0. Join the two 0V to 0V -> 0V. yes? || If you raise VoUt slightly Vbe upper turns off somewhat, Vout is pulled down & balAnce restored.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 'cojoye' also could just use nodal analysis on the output and find:$$\frac{v_o}{R_\text{L}}+I_{\text{E}_\text{QN}}=I_{\text{E}_\text{QP}}$$But as these are matched BJTs it must be that \$I_{\text{E}_\text{QN}}=I_{\text{E}_\text{QP}}\$. Therefore it follows that:$$\begin{align*}\frac{v_o}{R_\text{L}}+I_{\text{E}_\text{QN}}&=I_{\text{E}_\text{QP}}\\\\\frac{v_o}{R_\text{L}}&=0\:\text{A}&\therefore \quad v_o=0\:\text{V}\end{align*}$$But only a closed mathematical expression can *prove* that \$I_{\text{R}_\text{L}}=0\:\text{A}\$ for all \$V_\text{BB}\$ at \$v_i=0\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon comments should be for requesting clarification or suggestions for improving the question, not for answering it.

Comment: @BruceAbbott This is Se EE. Until now, at leasst, we have stayed relatively free of the rigorous straight jacketed interpretations of the rules which have so ham strung so many other SE groups. Hopefully 2020 vision will allow that sanity to continue yet awhile.  | I am nearly certain that you are aware by now how well I am or am not aware of the point you raise. So I'm not sure why you raise it. Or why you have not similarly "advised" Jonk. | The OP is clearly both trying hard and/but also very lost. A little more directness seemed/s in order. That's not always the case, of course.

Comment: @Jonk - Working at the level that th OP seems to be at, I;d hope that for the idealised devices he has proposed, then doe zero input there is always perfect inverse symmetry around the zero volts line. To me that seems to lead inescapably to Vo=0  with O/C load and hardly less so with finite load.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I've started a post. It's currently deleted. But the idea is to break a wire and to use a current mirror style of analysis (current causes VBE followed by presenting VBE to another BJT that causes current) in order to show that the current in the load resistor must always be zero in this case and therefore the output voltage must also always be zero. Not sure if I'll post it, or not. Just FYI. But I agree that the OP isn't prepared for the analysis. However, at least, it has the promise of stopping the hand-waving aspect and shows that there is a closed mathematical solution.

Comment: @Jonk. Yes - your deleted part answer is visible to me. It had never occurred to me in all my years on this site to use deletion as a way of building an answer progressively. Good idea.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks! And yes, I think that's the approach to making a proof. Of course, Bruce is off on a different direction. If the OP likes it, we are done and everything is good. If not, then the OP is actually seeking a proof and the approach I'm taking is the way to get there, I think. We shall see. I won't progress any further until I see the OP respond in a way that suggests I'm right. Otherwise, I'm happy with the argument you made. Hopefully, the OP also is.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon By the way, I got this practice of breaking wires like this from Dr. R. David Middlebrook's "Design Oriented Analysis" way of looking at things. Just FYI. (I look to my betters about how to see the world.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have this type of question, usually the best approach is to compute the base-emitter voltage of the transistors. This is what you tried to do, judging from your comments.

The base-emitter voltage of the NPN transistor is \$V_\mathrm{BB}/2 - v_\mathrm{O}\$. The base-emitter voltage of the PNP transistor is \$-V_\mathrm{BB}/2 - v_\mathrm{O}\$. Applying Kirchhoff’s current law at the output junction and substituting the diode equation yields

$$i_\mathrm{N} - i_\mathrm{P} = I_s e^{V_\mathrm{BB}/(2V_\mathrm{T})} (e^{-v_\mathrm{O}/V_\mathrm{T}} - e^{v_\mathrm{O}/V_\mathrm{T}}) = v_\mathrm{O} / R_\mathrm{L}.$$

The trivial solution of this equation is \$v_\mathrm{O} = 0\$. It is straight forward to show that this is the only solution. Note that the gradient for the LHS is decreasing while the gradient of the RHS is increasing.

[image: solution]

Although it is difficult to see, the LHS (blue) has the opposite sign of the RHS (red).

Comment: This is exactly the response I am looking for. I thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

> For an input voltage of 0V, the output voltage is 0V. However, I don't
>   understand why?

Ask a slightly different question:- why would it *not* be? Assuming the transistors are exactly complimentary the circuit is fully symmetrical, so it does not favor one over the other. Therefore there is no reason for the output to not be 0V. But how to prove it?

Let's simplify things a bit by making RL very large. Now In and Ip *must* be equal, and since the transistors have 'identical' characteristics they should both have the same Vbe magnitude. With those voltages equal the bias voltage is split evenly between them, and Vout = Vin.

Now make RL smaller. It doesn't draw any current because there is no voltage across it, so our assumption regarding In and Ip still holds.

Comment: All that makes sense. But I also think there is a crafty approach to strictly proving it using inescapable mathematics.

Comment: The problem with using crafty mathematics is that unless you are a math genius it doesn't help with understanding it. This why Richard Feynman said "If you think you understand quantum mechanics, you don't understand quantum mechanics.".

Comment: Sure. I get that. But I'm frankly not sure what the OP is actually after. There have been plenty of very good arguments already of the more "understanding nature" type. None of those seem to have been accepted. In fact, more like outright rejected. So this leaves us with a question. Is the OP seeking a proof? I can't tell. But the dialog so far suggests to me that this is the case. And a proof is possible. The question remains, what is the OP seeking? Right now, I'm leaning towards a proof. But that may just be me projecting.

Comment: I think the problem is 'answers' have been proposed in the comment area, which just confused the OP more (what has 'Ron' got to do with anything?). I prefer simple proofs where possible.

Comment: We each see a different part of the elephant, I suppose. You may be right. We'll see as things play out. I'm open, either way. (Hand-waving isn't so much a proof, by the way. But it's good to see that way, still.)

Comment: If the elephant has different parts it doesn't hurt to have descriptions of each part. And if you have an answer (even if it's not the whole or 'best' answer), write an answer not a comment. Having different perspectives can help. Also the OP is not the only person who may be looking to get something out of this. So if you have that crafty mathematical proof, bring it!

Comment: I may. But I have a 24/7-365 operation going here for business reasons and very little time to expend in the near-term. I've started a deleted post that illustrates the approach I see ahead. I'll expand it if it turns out the OP is looking for that kind of answer. If not, there will be another time and place, perhaps.

Comment: Does this kind of argument work? Say the input voltage is not zero and the load resistance is high. Then the two currents will also be the same. Hence the base-emitter voltages will be the same. However this line of reasoning starts to fail when you begin decreasing the load resistance.

Comment: @user110971 You'll find that the battery voltages will have to increase dramatically (towards infinity, but on a log curve) as you reduce the load resistance towards zero.

Comment: @jonk You don’t need to reduce the resistance to zero. Just enough for the load current to start approaching the quiescent current.

Comment: @user110971 Are you able to read my deleted answer below? If so, please let me know if you disagree with any part of it. I could use the help.

Comment: @jonk can’t see it.

Comment: @user110971 No problem. If the OP appears to want a proof, I'll open it up. If not, there's no point. (But I do find that \$\frac{V_\text{BB}}2=V_T\,\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{V_T}{R_\text{L}\:I_\text{SAT}}\right)\$.)

Comment: @user110971 (For stability, I mean.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the equally matched and biased transistors with two equal value resistors like this: -

[image]

Now ask yourself what the output voltage is.

Comment: I said that in comments - with far more detail. He said 0V - but he didn't know the answer to his question.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that just proves that equally intelligent (I'm not saying great minds of course) think alike!

Comment: I've heard it said: ""Great minds think alike. Fools seldom differ." :-). Likely neither applies here on this occasion :-).