# Why is the following assumption valid?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

For the following AB power amplifier VBB/2 is large enough such that both Qn and Qp are on for no input signal Vi, if output voltage is large and positive, it may be assumed that most $$i_{L} \approx i_{N}$$
[image: amplifier]

What justifies this assumption?

Comment: Where else can IL come from?

Comment: Homework?  What is \$i_L\$ if \$i_P = 0\$?

Comment: @TimWescott It is not homework, I am looking over my textbook and came across this assumption.

Comment: EXACT DUPLICATE OF [For the following amplifier, why is the output voltage 0 when input voltage is 0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/474741/3288) asked 3 days ago and given MUCH input by many people.

Comment: THIS IS AN EXACT DUPLICATE OF [THIS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/474741/3288) QUESTION - FOR WHICH YOU RECEIVED A VAST AMOUNT OF GOOD INPUT.  You are wasting people's time. You are wasting your own time. Read the past answers and understand them. This 'problem' is trivially simple. It SHOULD be completely obvious to you from what you know that the answers people have given you are correct - IF you worked through them and understood them. || ...

Comment: ..**VERY OBVIOUSLY** - if the top and bottom halves are equal except for polarity, so that they "mirror each other, which is a basic assumption, then the "pull up" and "pull down" MUST balance and the output lies exactly midway between the power supplies = 0V. ||The SE "Be Nice" policy tells us to be nice to newcomers. And/But - you must put a minimum of effort into looking at what people say. This is genuinely a trivial question when looked at "externally". You can work through a complex derivation if you wish - but, simple also works well. Just read the answers and comments from 3 days back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the positive side of v1 all load current is flowing through Qn and Qp is open.
In= IL and Ip=0.
And reversely  for negative side of vi:
Ip = Il and In=0.
The purpose of Vbb/2 is avoiding discontinuation of the output signal when v1<0.6 V.
It's the enhanced version of the pur AB class amplifier.

Don't know if this help you.